# Define a boost::function with a docstring (Boost::Python)

Tags: c++, boost-python, docstring

I simply have a function object:

```
boost::function<int(int)> func = /** ... **/;
```

And want to expose it to Python with a docstring.
But the obvious:

```
def("func", func, "Some boring documentation goes here.");
```

Fails with an amusing ~2500 lines message.

Any ideas?

---

**Edit:** I made other tests:

```
def("func", func); // doesn't compile

def("func",
   make_function(
     func,
     default_call_policies(),
     vector<int,int>()
   )
); // compiles

def("func",
   make_function(
     func,
     default_call_policies(),
     vector<int,int>()
   ),
   "Some boring documentation goes here"
); // doesn't compile
```

Comment: Does it work without the docstring? I would imagine the docstring is not your problem here.

Comment: Any reason why you can't expose the function you're wrapping directly to Python without the `boost::function` intermediary?

Comment: @KyleC no, you're right. but see my edit (the docstring *could* be the problem).

Comment: @Praetorian The `boost::function` comes from doing a `bind(...)`.

Comment: So, I can expose it via `make_function`, but if I add the docstring it fails.

Comment: One thing I have found with boost::python is though even it compiles sometimes it will not work during runtime, I can't test it in your case, but does your function work in runtime without the docstring?

Comment: @KyleC yeah, with `make_function` it works as expected. But when I add the docstring... you know. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`boost::python::def()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/def.html#def-spec) documentation mentions being able to provide a docstring only when provided a non-null function or member function pointer.  One [solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81158881b6498e40) is to wrap the function object call in a function:

```cpp
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int times_two(int x) { return x * 2; }

boost::function<int(int)> func = &times_two;

int times_two_wrap(int x) { return func(x); }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::def("times_two", &times_two_wrap,
              "returns two times the supplied value");
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> assert(6 == example.times_two(3))
>>> print help(example.times_two)

times_two( (int)arg1) -> int :
    returns two times the supplied value

    C++ signature :
        int times_two(int)
>>>
```

---

Boost.Python has multiple API layers.  The highest layer is mostly documented, but it makes use of a less-documented lower-level API.  In this particular case, it looks as though the higher-level API is poorly forwarding to the lower-level API.  One could instead create a python function using [`boost::python::make_function()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/make_function.html), then use the lower-level `boost::python::objects::add_to_namespace()` function, as [demonstrated](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f793fd1d281346a0) below:

```cpp
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int times_two(int x) { return x * 2; }

boost::function<int(int)> func = &times_two;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
   namespace python = boost::python;
   // Wrap the functor in a Python object.
   python::object py_func = python::make_function(
     func,
     python::default_call_policies(),
     boost::mpl::vector<int, int>());
   // Add the function directly to the namespace.
   python::objects::add_to_namespace(
     python::scope(), // current namespace,
     "times_two",     // function name,
     py_func,         // function,
     "returns two times the supplied value");
}
```

This produces the same output with the interactive usage.  The only notable behavioral difference between the two approaches is that the first example enables one to change the underlying implementation at runtime by assigning a new value to `func`.

Comment: Thank you. Keep in mind you can probably patch the docstring from C++: `object func = make_function(...)` and then `func["__doc__"] = "patched docstring"`.

Comment: @jmendeth: I tried this on a function object created with raw_function(). The code compiles, but running gives me an error message: _TypeError: 'Boost.Python.function' object does not support item assignment_

Comment: @jmendeth -- setattr() works: `object f = raw_function(&func, 1); setattr(f, "__doc__", str("doc")); def("func", f);`